# Unit testing react-helmet code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, react-helmet

I am using react-helmet to add elements to head element.

```
<Helmet>
     <title>title</title>
     <meta name="description" content="description" />
     <meta name="keywords" content="keywords" />
</Helmet>
```

And I am trying to write unit test like this:

```
it('should render metadata', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Metadata/>);
    // this is not working.
    expect(document.title).to.equal("title");
});
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but don't you need to refer to `wrapper` in your expect?
`expect(wrapper.title)...` or something to that effect.

Comment: Helmet doesn't render content so title won't be added to title.

Comment: sorry, title won't be added to document.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. I did following:

```
it('should render metadata', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Metadata/>);
    // this will return all the markup assigned to helmet
    // which will get rendered inside head.
    const helmet = Helmet.peek();
    expect(helmet.title).to.equal("title");
});
```

This does the trick for unit test.

Comment: Thank you, linked it here https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/168

Answer (score 8):

I was in a similar situation with react testing library and JSDOM, but I didn't want to make the test specific to the Helmet implementation because that's against the guiding principle of react testing library. I found that doing the obvious thing:

```
render(<App />)
await waitFor(...some DOM element)
expect(document.title).toEqual("title")
```

does ***not*** work even if the DOM element you're awaiting is rendered in the same render as the `<Helmet>`

However, this does work:

```
await waitFor(...some DOM element)
await waitFor( () => expect(document.title).toEqual("title"))
```

I presume that between React and Helmet there's some timing thing going on which means there's a delay between the rest of the DOM being rendered and the title being set in JSDOM.

Comment: "I didn't want to make the test specific to the Helmet implementation because that's against the guiding principle of react testing library". 
+1 Definitely prefer this approach just for this reason

Comment: this approach only can apply to title, other meta tag can't use

Comment: Can you add some real example, im lost with the waitFor and "some Dom element"

Comment: @ValRob see the documentation here https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor What I was getting at is that once you've waited once for the document to be rendered, you will (might?) have to wait again for the title to be set correctly. What goes inside the `waitFor` depends on what will appear on the screen once the document has been rendered (or you might actually use a `findBy` query).   There's an example including `waitFor` here https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test helmet with only jest and no furhter modules like enzyme etc. you can do the following:

add:

```js
jest.mock('react-helmet', () => {
    const React = require('react');
    const plugin = jest.requireActual('react-helmet');
    const mockHelmet = ({children, ...props}) =>
        React.createElement('div', {
            ...props,
            className: 'mock-helmet',
        }, children);
    return {
        ...plugin,
        Helmet: jest.fn().mockImplementation(mockHelmet),
    };
});
```

to your `setupFiles` in the jest config.

Now it will render a `<div className="mock-helmet">` that you can use for snapshot tests or inspect further and check if a certain `<meta>` tag is present inside.

Answer (score 2):

Today i tested adding simply `<HelmetProvider>` in the return of the react function.
Before that, i had errors like

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')`

when coming to the render command in the test.
After adding the `<HelmetProvider>` tests are passed without error.